# Running python code directly in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to run a python program directly in vim. I type

```
:w !python
```

I get error

> 'no module named...' or 'no such file or directory: 'file.json''.

It occurs only when I load file after opening vim. When I start vim typing `gvim filename.py`, it works fine (`:w !python` works). What is wrong here?

Comment: I'm thinking this is caused because you're not running the script from the same directory. That might be the reason the script is failing to load `file.json`. Try starting vim when you're inside the same directory, load the file and do `:w !python`

Comment: I am using Windows and start VIM from my Start menu. On my Linux computer it is the same problem but I think it is weird to start VIM inside the same directory. I may change file and then what? Reload VIM? It is weird...

Comment: In that case, how about changing working directory to the directory where the file is and then running it. Like `:cd %:h` and then `:w !python`

Comment: If the program you are running is contained in a single file and you don't want to change directories, then you can use `:w !python %`. The percent sign `%` represents the current file open in vim. This is like calling `:w !python /path/to/current/file.py`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this to my _vimrc config file:

```
noremap <F5> :w !python %<CR>
inoremap <F5> <ESC>:w !python %<CR>
```